# Update Query in laravel 5.4

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

How can I update multiple rows

I'm getting below array

```
  [
     "3",
     "4",
     "5"
  ]
```

My Controller

```
$answers= $request->get('option'); //answers array
foreach ($answers as  $answer)
{
   Answer::where('question_id', 1)->update(
          ['customer_id' => 1,
          'answer' => $answer]);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`update()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#updates) method:

```
Answer::where('question_id', 2)->update(['customer_id' => 1, 'answer' => 2]);
```

> The update method expects an array of column and value pairs representing the columns that should be updated

Don't forget to add `customer_id`, `answer` to the [`$fillable`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#mass-assignment) array:

```
protected $fillable = ['customer_id', 'answer'];
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @Alexey Mezenin, I have updated my could you please take a look.

Comment: @ManjunathAM you're using $1 instead of 1 in updated code.

Comment: The code is correct and it will work if you've added fillable array as I've shown.

Comment: The above code is not working properly it stores only last value.Can you please help on that.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using  query builder then use bellow query

```
DB::table('answers')
            ->where('question_id', 2)
            ->update(array('customer_id' => 1, 'answer' => 2]);
```

and if you are using Eloquent ORM then use bellow query

```
App\Answers::where('question_id', 2)->update(['customer_id' => 1,'answer'=>2]);
```

Comment: Thank you, @Margi.

Answer (score 2):

You can update with simple following query.

```
DB::table('answers')->where('id',2)->update(['customer_id' => 1, 'answer' => 2]);
```

It's better to use Eloquent Model like,

```
Answer::where('id',2)->update(['customer_id' => 1, 'answer' => 2]);
```

If you have not added these column in `$fillable` property of model then, you can update with after find like,

```
$answer = Answer::find(2);
$answer->customer_id = 1;
$answer->answer = 2;
$answer->save();
```

Hope you understand.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Sagar Gautam , I have updated my could you please take a look.

Comment: @ManjunathAM for each array data , customer id is same ?

Comment: Yes, @Sagar Gautam same.

Comment: Just simpy use foreach loop what's the problem ?

Comment: What you want seems quit unclear for me, Code is correct but every time same row will be updated since you have same value of id field.

Comment: @ManjunathAM The question you have asked before and now are quit different